# Raster to ASCII in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, ascii

I have a raster file (DEM or .tif), but I need to transform it into a .txt file (ASCII). How can I do this in QGIS (Quantum GIS)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to Raster -> Translate (convert format) -> on "Ouput file" select Arc/Info ASCII Grid

http://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Export_Raster_to_asc